# What is meant by "gradient of the slope"?

Tags: terminology, vector-analysis

What is meant by "gradient of the slope"?

Particularly, I found this in the context of ground slopes (i.e. "valleyness").

Is it "steepness of slope"?

It's possible that "gradient" is used in some broader than differential calculus meaning, e.g. some "geographic" meaning. Yet, since it's about slope, then those two are perhaps related notions.

Comment: Sounds like an awkward phrasing although the two words are related. The gradient is a vector, while the slope is a real number.

Comment: The points about "needs context" are unnecessary, I find. The context is that an author talks about ground with valleys having a gradient of the slope (of a ground). It's clear that the ground has a slope (since if there's valleyness), but what's then gradient of this?

Comment: I'd like to see an exact quote where this phrasing is used. Maybe you could post a screenshot.

Comment: @littleO These terms appear broadly in geographic literature, I find. But I also found: https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/znyqtfr/revision/1. So yes, it's "steepness of slope", I think.

Comment: Slope or gradient is a measure of how steep you climb vertically  in comparison to your horizontal displacement. Expressed $\Delta y/ \Delta x$ or $dy/dx$,  gradient  of slope is needlessly repetitive.